# Git: Overwrite a Folder with one from another Branch

Tags: git

I have two branches:
master and B

I want to finally merge B to master, but B contains some changes in the folder /crap which I cannot merge.

I would like discard all differences between crap/ in master and Branch B.

Currently I tried this

```
git rm crap/
git checkout master -- crap/
```

This fails with Unlink of file X failed or unable to stat just-written file
Note crap/ is a folder and contains subfolders as well, like crap/more_crap/

Comment: Sorry, I left a comment before, but I misunderstood your question, and I'm confused about the slashes you used. Is the `crap` folder really in the root, as you indicated with `/crap`, or are we really talking about a `crap` folder inside your main project, as you seemed to indicate with `crap/`?

Comment: If I understand well enough what you're trying to do, you want to keep the `crap` folder in master, but you don't want any of the `crap` changes from B. If that's right, here's what I would do: a `--no-commit` merge from B to master. That will stage all your files for commit, without actually committing them. All the merge changes will be in the stage ready for commit. Then you can `git reset HEAD crap/.` to remove all the `crap` from the stage. Then you can just commit and you'll get everything from B except the `crap`.

Comment: @GreatBigBore Yes, it's a folder inside the main project, I will edit the question, thx